# Signals don't work in aiohttp

Tags: python, signals, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I have simple asynchronous application written on `aiohttp`. I need to extend `app` instance on server startup or shutdown, but signals doesn't work at all (the function never executes):

```py
from aiohttp import web

app = web.Application()

async def on_startup(app):
    app['key'] = "need to save something here"

app.on_startup.append(on_startup)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    srv = loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.gather(
        loop.create_server(app.make_handler(), host='0.0.0.0', port=8000)
    ))
    loop.run_forever()
```

How can I extend the `app` instance via callback? Does somebody have an idea?

P.S. I use stable `aiohttp` version (3.0.9).

Comment: When you say "signal" what do you mean?  What signal-handling code have you tried?

Comment: @Jean-PaulCalderone, I mean the [signals in aiohttp](http://aiohttp.readthedocs.io/en/stable/web_advanced.html#aiohttp-web-signals). I need to use a signal that sends after server started (`on_startup`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I spend a time in search of solution... and I found it! I decide to explore the `web.run_app()` method to understand how it works. So, this method use `AppRunner().setup()` to configure application before it will be running. I'm not sure that it's the best solution, but it works :) Well, the final code looks like the following:

```py
from aiohttp import web

app = web.Application()

async def on_startup(app):
    app['key'] = "need to save something here"

app.on_startup.append(on_startup)

# Create an instance of the application runner
runner = web.AppRunner(app, handle_signals=True)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    srv = loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.gather(
        runner.setup(),  # Configure the application before run the server
        loop.create_server(app.make_handler(), host='0.0.0.0', port=8000)
    ))
    loop.run_forever()
```

Answer (score 4):

Try the below if there is no reason you should use low-level API like `make_handler()`, it will work with `on_startup` signal .

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    web.run_app(app, host='0.0.0.0', port=8000)
```

`run_app()` will use the `get_event_loop()` internally for the loop it use.